# Training zones and training plans

Tags: training, bicycling

I decided to recently try create my own cycling training plan, but I think I misinterpreted some of the info and am overtraining. I used Strava to get a lot of information and also read up from online searches.

I started off the a Strava training plan, combined with this info for custom HR zones: https://www.strava.com/athlete/training-plans/cycling-training-glossary but interpreted the "% hr" as "% max" and not "% CTS", and am guessing it's not a sustainable plan. I've just read up on % Threshold, with this breakdown:
[image: heart rate zones]

from [this article](https://roadcyclinguk.com/how-to/six-things-need-know-training-zones.html).

I did a "tempo" training ride today and got feedback that "its more like a threshold workout", so am here wanting to clarify.

Here's 2 specific workouts that I got from a training plan and how I interpreted it, and wanted to validate the correction I should be making:

1. 4 x 12m Steady State - Initially: "Steady state = 92% - 94% of max, i.e. 174 - 176bpm". Adjusted: "92% - 94% of CTS 8m avg, i.e. closer to 78% - 80% of max or 145bpm - 150bpm"
2. 3 x 20m Tempo intervals - Initially: "Tempo = 88% - 90% of max, i.e. 164bpm - 168bpm". Adjusted: "88% - 90% of threshold, i.e. 74% - 76% of max or 138bpm - 142"

These new zones feel super conservative to me, I can comfortably ride at 90% max for 3 x 20m intervals (6m rest between each), and feel like this is improving more than 75% for 3 x 20m. Am looking for a slightly more aggressive training plan and wondering how I should be training (1 - 2 hours available a day, 5 - 6 days a week).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goals actually.

And on what you want to improve. Instead on focusing on zones, why dont you focus better on volume of training?

Because you dont even mention about it: its just a 3x meters and thats it.

If you feel a certain zone is conservative try to increase volume.

But again, it really come down to what feature you're trying to improve.